# How to create these pixel effects in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to create any of the following effects in illustrator:

[image]
[image]

Would be great if someone could guide me or provide me with a suitable tutorial.

Comment: Hi C0dez, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Those both appear to be created by a person purposefully drawing squares. A lot of design is simply 'drawing it' rather than just using automated effects.

Answer (score 5):

**The first one**

You can just create a square and use object - transform - move (and make sure to hit copy) to move the square at the desired length (vertical or horizontal).

I just made a 10 x 10 pixel square and moved the square 12 pixels downwards.

[image: move options]

Then press CTRL + D to repeat that action.

Select the entire row and go to object - transform - move and now select a horizontal of 12px (or whatever distance you're working with). Then delete some of the squares.

[image: group of squares]

Then select the outer squares and go to object - transform - scale. Select percents like 50% and then 25% for the farthest right squares. Then randomly select squares and give them different colors.

[image: scale]

**For the second effect**

I think they might have used a scatter brush. See a Adobe video https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-create-scatter-brush.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using the traditional way which is using the forms tool and using it as squares. I used to do it on PS for pixel art. I know it will take you some time but it's worth.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. It takes a long time and I am struggling with the color choices. Wish there was a wrap or effect which generates Square pixels.

Comment: @C0dez I'm sure there's plenty of plugins out there but they will cost you some money and I think this is a good way to train yourself if you need it in the future.

Comment: @C0dez If you're having trouble with picking colors I would suggest using https://kuler.adobe.com/. You can search by keywords and sync them to illustrator. But there are also plenty of other swatch resources out there.